# The phrase "iron out bugs"

Tags: etymology, phrases, idioms

Any idea how the moderately gruesome phrase *iron out bugs* originated? It brings a wonderfully vivid picture to my mind's eye!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a combination of two separate metaphorical ideas that are not etymologically linked.

The first - *iron out* - is a phrasal verb meaning [to resolve](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/iron+out).

The second - *bugs* - refers to a malfunction of computer hardware, and its [origins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging#Origin) are debatable.

Combine the two, and you arrive at *resolve computer malfunctions*.

Comment: I don't know about *debatable* -- The story of a moth caught in a relay and found by computer pioneer Grace Hopper is an article of faith to some computer scientists.

Comment: @pavium That is the apocryphal explanation, and makes for a nice story, but the [usage](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-bug1.htm) [dates](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bug) to far earlier than that.

Comment: That's the thing about faith: it's often irrational.

Comment: The phrase (like *bug*) predates widespread knowledge of computing – it occurs [in a 1931 Materials Engineering textbook](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=e8cnAAAAMAAJ&q=%22iron+out+the+bugs%22&dq=%22iron+out+the+bugs%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi277favbHSAhUDhbwKHfTPC9EQ6wEIODAH). And in modern usage, it is not restricted to software bugs, as we see in a [Jack Nicklaus memoir](http://www.smh.com.au/news/tennis/hewitt-tipped-to-iron-out-the-bugs-for-open/2006/01/10/1136863239268.html). I suspect the modern meaning of *bug* has caused to often refer to software but this is not exclusive

Answer (score 2):

*Iron out bugs* means, basically, to **debug**.  It comes from a conjunction of the phrase *iron out*, figurative for *resolve (a problem)*, and the programming term *bug*.

According to [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/iron+out):

> ***-Verb phrase***
>   **26.** iron out,
>   **a.**  to iron or press (an item of clothing or the like).
>   **b.**  to remove (wrinkles) from by ironing.
>   **c.**  to resolve or clear up (difficulties, disagreements, etc.): *The problem was ironed out months ago.*

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "Iron Out" - [Rust Stain Remover](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=iron%20out&safe=strict&biw=743&bih=515&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZq_G5otLQAhULi5QKHSmmBc8Q_AUICCgB&gws_rd=cr&ei=KLc_WJ6KHI3X0gT10ZfIAQ#gws_rd=cr&imgrc=s7V5U9oEUshDKM%3A), to remove everything.

As for bugs, as @Hal  saids: it is malfunction of computer hardware. Therefore, "iron out bugs" means remove computer bugs.